# Capture a Stata-style log in R (comments, commands, and output)

Tags: r, stata

I'm hoping to use R to capture a log that shows comments, commands, and output from the script.

`txtStart()` from [TeachingDemos](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TeachingDemos/index.html) gets close, but it omits comments. This script

```
library(TeachingDemos)
txtStart("log.txt")

# Step 1: Some math:
1+2

txtStop()
```

makes the following `log.txt`:

```
> 1 + 2
[1] 3
```

But ideally I'd get

```
# Step 1: Some math:
> 1 + 2
[1] 3
```

I also tried `sink()`, but it only gives output. So in the above example `log.txt` would be:

```
[1] 3
```

**Update**

@rawr's comment helps a lot. If `myscript.r` is

```
# Step 1: Some math:
1+2
```

Then this will get you the comments, commands, and output:

```
sink("mylog.txt")
source('myscript.r', echo = TRUE)
sink()
```

`mylog.txt` after running this is:

```
> # Step 1: Some math:
> 1+2
[1] 3
```

I'm leaving the question open since I'm still hoping for a way to do this in one script, Stata-style.

Comment: This sounds like a standard use case for R Markdown / R notebooks / Quarto docs, have you looked at those?

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring! I've looked and my understanding is that all those options require additional code to indicate text comments vs. R code...I'm hoping for an even simpler solution that doesn't require markdown syntax.

Comment: `source('script.R', echo = TRUE)` ?

Comment: @rawr that helps a lot. Updated the question to show your code

Comment: A less user-friendly solution is to run R in batch mode. `R CMD BATCH your_script.R` will automatically generate a `.Rout` file with the same name as your script giving all the input (comments, etc.) and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample R Markdown file. It doesn't require much in terms of markdown syntax, but maybe still more than you want: there's a header and the code chunks are encased between ```` ```{r} ```` and ```` ``` ````.

````
---
title: "my_great_file"
output: html_document
---

Step 1: Some math:

```{r}
1+2
```
````

Producing an html file like this:  (or a pdf, or word doc, or powerpoint, etc.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the example! It seems like this might be the closest I can get

Answer (score 0):

I found this package with a result very similar to the log file in Stata.

```
install.packages('TeachingDemos')
library(TeachingDemos)
txtStart("transcript.txt")
txtComment(' Step 1: Some math:')
1+2
txtStop()
```

The result is:
Step 1: Some math:

> 1 + 2
> [1] 3